# SQL; Full left, right, upper, inner, backwards joins

Tags: sql, join

Can't seem to get my head around this.  I have three tables (stock,sales,POs) relating to products with one common field which can join them all toghether.  I have a fourth table which has all the products in it.  The product may or may not have information in these tables (stock,sales,POs) but will have a record in the Product table.

I need to end with up one row per product which has information in one of the three tables (stock, sales and POs).

A simplified view of the tables are below:

**Product Table**, Ref, Description

**Stock Table**, Ref, Current_Stock

**Sales Table**,Ref, Qty_Sold

**POs Table**, Ref, Qty_Outstanding

I need to end with the following:

Ref, Description, Current_Stock, Qty_Sold, Qty_Outstanding

Thanks

Nig

Comment: What RDBMS are you using. is Ref a unique Product ID in all 4 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, the easiest and most straightforward way to do this would be to left-join all the detail tables to the `Product` table, then filter out the products that have *no* matches at all.

So, this would essentially be @Santhosh's solution with a small tweak (emphasized):

```
SELECT
  pr.Ref,
  pr.Description,
  st.Current_Stock,
  sa.Qty_Sold,
  po.Qty_Outstanding
FROM Product pr
LEFT JOIN Stock st ON st.Ref = pr.Ref
LEFT JOIN Sales sa ON sa.Ref = pr.Ref
LEFT JOIN POs   po ON po.Ref = pr.Ref
WHERE st.Ref IS NOT NULL
   OR sa.Ref IS NOT NULL
   OR so.Ref IS NOT NULL
;
```

There's also a somewhat less obvious alternative: union all the detail tables, then pivot the detail data. The resulting set will only contain references to the products that have at least some detail information. So, you could then just inner join the resulting set to `Product` to access the product descriptions for the output.

If your SQL product supports the PIVOT clause, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT
  p.Ref,
  p.Description,
  s.Current_Stock,
  s.Qty_Sold,
  s.Qty_Outstanding
FROM (
  SELECT
    Ref,
    Current_Stock,
    Qty_Sold,
    Qty_Outstanding
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Ref,
      'Current_Stock' AS Attribute,
      Current_Stock   AS Value
    FROM Stock
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Ref,
      'Qty_Sold',
      Qty_Sold
    FROM Sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Ref,
      'Qty_Outstanding',
      Qty_Outstanding
    FROM POs
  ) d
  PIVOT (
    SUM(Value) FOR Attribute IN (
      Current_Stock,
      Qty_Sold,
      Qty_Outstanding
    )
  ) p
) s
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.Ref = s.Ref
;
```

There's also an older and more universal method of pivoting, for which you need to employ grouping and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  p.Ref,
  p.Description,
  SUM(CASE Attribute WHEN 'Current_Stock'   THEN d.Value END) AS Current_Stock,
  SUM(CASE Attribute WHEN 'Qty_Sold'        THEN d.Value END) AS Qty_Sold,
  SUM(CASE Attribute WHEN 'Qty_Outstanding' THEN d.Value END) AS Qty_Outstanding
FROM (
  SELECT
    Ref,
    'Current_Stock' AS Attribute,
    Current_Stock   AS Value
  FROM Stock
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Ref,
    'Qty_Sold',
    Qty_Sold
  FROM Sales
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Ref,
    'Qty_Outstanding',
    Qty_Outstanding
  FROM POs
) d
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.Ref = d.Ref
GROUP BY
  p.Ref,
  p.Description
;
```

Comment: Thanks Andriy, I've opted to use left joins and a where clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.REF, P.DESCRIPTION, S.CURRENT_STOCK, SALES.QTY_SL, POS.QTY_OUTSTANDING
FROM PRODUCTS P
LEFT JOIN STOCK S
ON S.REF = P.REF
LEFT JOIN SALES SALES
ON SALES.REF = P.REF
LEFT JOIN POS
ON POS.REF = P.REF
```

Comment: Using a left outer join will give me everything in the Product table regardles of whether I have records in the other table.  I want to ignore products which don't have any relating records in the three tables (Stock,Sales,POs). Maybe I need a WHERE clause?

Comment: use inner join instead of Left Keyword in the query.

Comment: Unfortunately INNER JOIN's will only return records where each table has data for each ref: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05768/5

Comment: The above example in sqlfiddle demonstrates this.  There are 4 primary products, yet only 1 is displayed if we use INNER JOINs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `REF` is *unique* and is used like a *foreign key* in all tables

Maybe you can try

```
SELECT pt.REF, pt.DESCRIPTION, st.CURRENT_STOCK, sat.QTY_SOLD, pot.QTY_OUTSTANDING
FROM PRODUCTTABLE pt
INNER JOIN STOCKTABLE st
ON st.REF = pt.REF
INNER JOIN SALESTABLE sat
ON sat.REF = pt.REF
INNER JOIN POSTABLE pot
ON pot.REF = pt.REF
```

I just love this [Graphical summary of join operations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) very usefull!

Comment: Using an inner join will only give me a row back where the three tables (stock,sales,POs) ALL have a foreign key. (nice link by the way)

Comment: how many rows in Product table do you have ? with different REF?

Comment: There's about half a million rows in the product table.

Comment: is there some products who don't have any sales,stock or pos? these records will be ignored

Comment: Exactly, some products in the "Product" table will not have records in the sales, stock or POs tables.  These records I do not want to display.

Comment: Hi bAN,  thanks for the repsonse and your sample (haven't come across sqlfiddle before, very handy! :-) 

However, the results you get from it do not match my requirements.  I should see another row for "TEST2" with "Stock" showing NULL and "Sales" showing 4.

Comment: So you have to replace the inner join with stock by left join! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8f1d/21